# UICollectionView horizontal scroll with vertical header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I am creating a UICollectionView which scrolls horizontally but with a vertical section header.

My problem is that for horizontal scrolling, the section header defaults to the left side of the collection view and I cannot adjust it to the top of the UICollectionView.

I have checked out various solutions which includes DateFlowLayout which unfortunately does not work anymore.

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309918/application-crash-when-set-header-of-uicollectionview-horizontally/31309991?noredirect=1#comment50613185_31309991 may help

Comment: I am also facing this issue , i cant believe its such a common problem and there is no api with UIcollectionViewFlowlayout to resolve this issue

Comment: This pod did it for me: https://github.com/toshi0383/HorizontalStickyHeaderLayout

Comment: I found it easier to place the collection view into a table view cell. That allows you to use the table view section headers.

Answer (score 5):

You have to implement your own collection view layout to do so.

The easiest would be to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override

`- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

to give the frame you wish for the header

Comment: I don't want to edit the bounds of the header but just the header position

Comment: Sorry, I meant the frame, position, size,... whatever you want :)
Please read the documentation for for info
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/

Comment: I have been searching around the internet and also the doc but their usage seems to be very basic and does not cover section header at all. I am lost as to how to proceed with that method. How do I reference my section header in that method?

Comment: @chiken if you find the solution please share it I am facing the same problem. thank you

Comment: @NiibFouda this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826740/uicollectionview-special-horizontal-flow-multiple-sections